# Nested if to ignore blanks

Tags: vba, excel

Long time user of the site, First time to have a question asked.

A little background

I had a coding encyclopedia in my last job, knew excel and VBA inside out, so my problems where only as complicated as walking to is desk.

I have now moved on and have a need for this assistance more than ever.

I have an issue, I am using a spread sheet to calculate Time in days and hours between 2 dates.

For SLA reporting

Some cells on the in the series will be blank so I want there returned as " "

And I keep the generic issue with formula use help or function wizard.

The formula I am using is to get the values in my target cell are:

```
INT(G2-F2)&" Days "&HOUR(MOD(G2-F2,1))&" Hour "&MINUTE(MOD(G2-F2,1))&" Minutes"
```

If `F2` is blank so will `G2` so the if can be performed on either cell or both.

Can you guys guide me in the right direction on how to nest so blank are returned as " " in the target cell?

Is an OR if the answer or does a `ISBLANK` suit better?

Thank you

Wayne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you just want:

```
=IF(F2="","",INT(G2-F2)&" Days "&HOUR(MOD(G2-F2,1))&" Hour "&MINUTE(MOD(G2-F2,1))&" Minutes")
```

Note: I don't see any need for the MOD in there, as it happens.